# freemarker exception

Tags: struts2, freemarker

I'm using struts2.1.8 and freemarker2.3.15. After the program got online, it throws IOException. The stack trace only shows a lot of filter, I cannot tell what's wrong from the stack trace, hoping anybody has ever seen this kind of error and give a hand.

```
java.io.IOException: There was an error loading the template on an earlier attempt; it is attached as a cause
    freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.throwLoadFailedException(TemplateCache.java:400)
    freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplate(TemplateCache.java:278)
    freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplate(TemplateCache.java:235)
    freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:487)
    freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:459)
    org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerResult.doExecute(FreemarkerResult.java:168)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:362)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:266)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MessageStoreInterceptor.intercept(MessageStoreInterceptor.java:204)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)


java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.creditease.core.exception.ExceptionInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionInterceptor.java:42)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MessageStoreInterceptor.intercept(MessageStoreInterceptor.java:204)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.creditease.p2p.interceptor.AccessInterceptor.intercept(AccessInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
```

Comment: Which type internet did you use? chrome or firefox?

Comment: I have tried chrome firefox and IE, the error

Comment: Why do we see two exceptions that has no 'caused by' between them? Is that still the nested cause exception? The nested cause exception of the IOException would tell what the problem was while loading the template.

Comment: So on localhost it works fine?

Comment: @ddekany I didn't post whole trace, it's too long. There is "Root Cause" above the NullPointerException. The stack trace of NullPointerException shows a lot of filter, I can tell what is really wrong.

Comment: @AleksandrM It works fine on both my computer and the test environment

Comment: So you are saying that the nested cause exception of that `IOException` is the `NullPointerException` shown above. In that case, you should look into the source code at `ExceptionInterceptor.java:42`, `DefaultActionInvocation.java:237`, etc., to see what can possibly cause the `NullPointerException`. It's maybe also helpful to know that the error seems to occur when xwork2 or creditease simply tries to get (load?) the template source code, not when the template is executed. So if you know where do the templates come from, it's maybe easier to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe happening because your production application server was started from some path it cannot access. Try to start your server from the path it can access and with root credentials.

Comment: Only some of the pages cannot be accessed, not all of them.

Comment: The problem disappear after restart. But the same problem still comes up some time

Comment: You mean after restart? Or it happens randomly on working machine?